# Error when trying to retrieve data from the network following post Request to retrieve Image not showing in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapps-canvas, http-headers

I have the following Flow that Retrieves chemical Images dynamically from ChemSpider Depending on the SMILES entered. The steps for this flow generally are:

1. User inputs Text
2. Appends this to URL (Encoded)
3. send HTTP GET request to get the boxy of this page (Actually does this twice as there is a redirect)
4. create a file using the body of this request in a library called ImageTest/Images
5. Then send HTTP post request to a column called Images within a list called QSAR Analysis SUbmission Data

I want these images to appear as part of a gallery viewable within my Canvas PowerApp however the retrieved image, despite being in the right column, within powerapps the image just appears blank.

[image]

I require a unique Id from the get file metadata step however I have so far been unable to achieve this. The metadata step in the flow is not yet utilised.

Header Body:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.QSAR_x0020_Analysis_x0020_DataListItem"
    },
    "Title": "@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Title']}",
    "Image": "{\"type\":\"thumbnail\",\"fileName\":\"@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Title']}\",\"fieldName\":\"Image\",\"serverUrl\":\"https://xxx.sharepoint.com\",\"serverRelativeUrl\":\"/sites/xxx/ImageTest/Images/@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Title']}.png\"}"
}
```

I require a unique Id from the get file metadata step however I have so far been unable to achieve this. The metadata step in the flow is not yet utilised.

Where xxx is specific.

Note the above code is working to post the found image but fails to display as a property is missing.

**Update:**

[image]

OUTPUTS:

[image]
[image]

I suspect the Id may be the issue?

Comment: You are passing `Id` (item ID) to `id` property in body - here you have to pass the UniqueID metadata of image from SharePoint library. Are Attachments enabled for your "QSAR Analysis Submission Data" list?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP I havent yet explored doing this using attachments but that is the next idea. 

When you say I have to pass the UniqueID Metadata of image from sharepoint library this is where I become confused. Firstly UniqueID itself doesn't appear to be a term in powerautomate. Only ID and item Id are available options. Inserting the get Metadata step to get id, it is just the same id as previously returned. So I think the real issue right now is what unique id should I use and how do I get this?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP I did a further test using a GET request and Parsing JSON to yield multiple parameters and this provides id, guid etc but again non of these non of these yield the desired result. 

If you have an example screenshot using powerautomate passing the id from metadata step or get properties step I think this would become obvious to me.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP Please see latest updates showing changes and outputs. the flow runs and says its passed but still get the server error on power apps. I suspect this may be an issue with the id being passed but from your messages I am unsure what I may be doing wrong at this stage. The id (unique) is in this example: 

`%252fImageTest%252fImages%252fSilicate.png` and yet this causes the error.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP  I have got it to work using attachments but really if getting the items to be viewable via image this would be neater.